# Lenovo X1 Nano 2nd USB-C port not working: "USB device not recognised"

Tags: usb, drivers, windows-11

Whenever I connect a working webcam or an external HDD to the non-Thunderbolt USB-C port, I receive the following error.

[image]

(Windows 11)

I have installed the latest drivers.

I have performed a pin-hole reset.

The same error occurs.

Lenovo support says the motherboard needs to be replaced.

Are there no other software troubleshooting steps I can take, like reinstalling the USB drivers perhaps?

Help appreciated.

Comment: `Are there no other software troubleshooting steps I can take` Well, I suppose you can always test with a new Windows installation, if you will.

Comment: The port on the motherboard is most likely bad.